# Limit google autocomplete to a postal code

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Trying to work with the Google Autocomplete without maps, but it's being troublesome.

```
<script>
  var autocomplete;
  var countryRestrict = {country: 'NO', postalCode: '0365'}
  function initAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (document.getElementById('address-field')),
      { types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
      });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

when I add `postalCode`to countryRestrict it stops working, yet I see in their own example that they seem to be restricting it by using the example:

```
componentRestrictions: {country: "AU", postalCode: "2000"}
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction

Is it possible for me to limit the address autocomplete to a given postal code?

Answer (score 4):

Currently it's not possible, the only supported componentRestriction for an [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) is `country`
(The linked example is an implementation of geocoding, where more componentRestrictions are supported )

Adding other componentRestrictions than the supported options results in a script-error which breaks the Autocomplete

Comment: alright thanks, I assume there might be a way to filter out any result (by not displaying them) if they don't belong to that post code, do you know of any examples out there that might do that?

Comment: The details for the suggested places(including the postcode) are not available when you see the dropdown, so it's not possible to filter anything before the details will be requested(when you select a place from the dropdown)

Comment: I'm thinking of doing it after

Comment: If you want to filtering the results of autocomplete, you can query to Google using Google Places API, then you can filter the results. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types